# nested for loop with bold tag

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

Is it possible to write a nested for loop that builds a table and where the perfect squares are in bold?

I have this much now

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=10>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (j=1; j<=10; j++) {
        document.write('<tr>');
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            document.write('<td align ="center">',i*j,'</td>');
        }
        document.write("</tr>\n");  
    }
</script>
```

But I want to highlight the perfect squares in the table.
Does anyone

Comment: <table border=1 cellpadding=10>
<script type="text/javascript">


    for (j=1; j<=10; j++) {
     document.write('<tr>');
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
     document.write('<td align ="center">',i*j,'</td>');
     }
   document.write("</tr>\n"); 
  }
</script>

Oops! Here's the code I have so far.

Comment: Add that to the question. And format code as code.

Comment: @WesleyJohnson, From wikipedia: `a number that is a product of some integer with itself, e.g. 9 is a square number, its square root is 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mmhDR/

`j` is often used as the second loop variable, `k` after that, etc.

```
window.onload=function(){
    var t = document.createElement('table');
    for(var i =1;i<11;i++){
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for(var j=1;j<11;j++){
            var td=document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML=''+(j*i);
            if(j==i){
                td.className="bold";
            }
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        t.appendChild(tr);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(t);
};
```

edit: Using document.write():

http://jsfiddle.net/8vTg7/

```
<style type="text/css" >
table{
    margin:10px;
}
td{
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
.bold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<table>');
    for(var i =1;i<11;i++){
        document.write('<tr>');
        for(var j=1;j<11;j++){
            document.write('<td ');
            if(j==i){
                document.write('class="bold"');
            }
            document.write('>');
            document.write(''+(i*j));

            document.write('</td>');
        }
        document.write('</tr>');
    }
    document.write('</table>');
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with just one document.write()?

Comment: I like this. Uses the specific situation to avoid the need for an `isSquare()` method.

Comment: Fileas, FWIW `document.write()` really should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Edited Walkerneo's second solution to use just one `document.write()`: http://jsfiddle.net/DWQjs/ (...and throughly broke jsFiddle's syntax highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the problem.

```
 <table border="1"> 
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var outHTML="";
   var r, c;
     for (r=1;r<=10;r++) {

       outHTML += "<tr>";
        for (c=1;c<=10;c++) {
           if (r==c)
             outHTML += "<td><strong>" + (r*c) + "</strong></td>";
         else
            outHTML += "<td>" + (r*c) + "</td>";
       }
     outHTML += "</tr>";
   }
    document.writeln(outHTML);    
</script> 
</table>
```